# ImportError in running django from twisted

Tags: python, django, twisted, python-import

I'm trying to run a Twisted program, which serves some requests and also runs a Django app through WSGI, and routes some requests to it. Folder structure is something like this:

```
code
  |-- __init__.py
  |-- main.py
  |-- django_proj
  |     |-- __init__.py
  |     |-- manage.py
  |     |-- django_proj
  |     |     |-- __init__.py
  |     |     |-- settings.py
  |     |     |-- ...
  |     |-- django_app
  |     |     |-- __init__.py
  |     |     |-- models.py
  |     |     |-- ...
```

now, in `django_proj/django_proj/settings.py` I have this line:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_proj.django_app',
    ...
)
```

and I run the program when I'm in `code` folder like this: `python ./main.py`, and it runs without problem. But when I need to run something with `manage.py`, like running `manage.py migrate` I need to go inside `code/django_proj` folder and run it; but then it says:

```
ImportError: No module named django_app
```

and I need to change the line in `INSTALLED_APPS` to:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_app',
    ...
)
```

but if I leave it like this, I can't run `python ./main.py`! Because it will say:

```
ImportError: No module named django_app
```

So up until now, I used to change this line back & forth based on what I needed to do at the moment.
What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions: either move `manage.py` to `code` (recommended).

Or: use `python -m django_proj.manage`.

Whatever you choose, you'll have to change all your relative imports to absolute imports. That is, from `django_proj.settings` to `django_proj.django_proj.settings`.

Relative imports are nasty and lead the kind of problems you are experiencing now. (This is the reason why relative imports have been removed from Python 3.)

For more information, see [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159503/whats-wrong-with-relative-imports-in-python#159505) from [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters).

---

I see now that your `code` has an `__init__.py`. Is it really needed? If not, remove it. If it's needed, then you'll still be using imports relative to `code`, even with my solution.

This implies that you'll have to move all of your scripts out of `code`, and prefix all of your imports with `code`.

Comment: on the 2nd way: it gives me `ImportError: No module named settings`

Comment: the 1st way says the same too.

Comment: Thank you @Andrea! changing settings import inside `manage.py` and running through `python -m` does the job!

Comment: personally I think the 2nd way is better because it doesn't break the django app structure, and it doesn't pollute `code` folder with utilities of django app. Could you elaborate a bit more on why do you recommend the first way?

Comment: @sazary: because `python -m django_proj.manage` is not "obvious", and one may be tempted to run `python manage.py` instead.

Comment: that's right, but that will cause no damage because they will be simply confronted by some errors! I've written the right command in readme file, so I think I will go with the 2nd solution. Thanks for your time!